# How to paste the values for hidden columns in MPP file

Tags: vba

Currently am struck because currently my code is pasting only visible columns from MPP file

```
For Each TB In ActiveProject.TaskTables 
      If TB.Name = ActiveProject.CurrentTable Then 
          Exit For 
      End If 
Next TB
```

My question is How to get all hidden columns from MPP, MY code should paste the values for hidden columns as well

For Ex:- Resource name will be hidden in MPP File in one of the view But in my Source file we have values for that so My code should search hidden Column and paste the value

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Hello Nathan_Sav

Comment: Hello Nathan_Sav , Currently my code does is It will traversal from first Column to last and copy into the array, But it does only for visible columns'to get the column count and names
For Each TB In ActiveProject.TaskTables
  If TB.Name = ActiveProject.CurrentTable Then
    Exit For
  End If
Next TB

Comment: Can I get some solution or hint for above my question, becuase currently its a blocker to me am not able to move on

Comment: `getfield` maybe with a loop of the fields to `.fields.count`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861413.aspx